# C# WinForms TableLayoutPanel is flickering while adding my row and How to stop it

Tags: c#, winforms

This code works fine like adding a row and deleting a row dynamically .But when i delete some of rows from table and then click the add button to add some rows into the panel then the flickering starts and increases while adding more rows.

Public Global Variables

```
 public TableLayoutPanel table;
 public int tablecol, tablerow;
```

Function for creating a table in Main Window.
This function creates a table with some header labels and Button named "ADD" .

```
public void createtable()
            {
                Label title = new Label(); title.Text = "Table Name";
                this.myw.right_panel.Controls.Add(title);
                TextBox tname = new TextBox(); tname.Width = 300;
                this.myw.right_panel.Controls.Add(tname);
                Button addrowbtn = new Button(); addrowbtn.Text = "ADD ROW";
                addrowbtn.Click += addrowbtn_Click;
                this.myw.right_panel.Controls.Add(addrowbtn);

                table = new TableLayoutPanel();
                table.Width = this.myw.right_panel.Width;
                table.Height = 400;
                table.AutoScroll = true;
                table.ColumnCount = 9;

                int col = 0;
                Label[] titlelbl = new Label[9];
                foreach(Label l in titlelbl)
                {
                    titlelbl[col++] = new Label();
                }
                titlelbl[0].Text = "NAME";
                titlelbl[0].Width = 200;
                titlelbl[1].Text = "TYPE";
                titlelbl[2].Text = "NOT NULL";
                titlelbl[3].Text = "PK";
                titlelbl[4].Text = "AI";
                titlelbl[5].Text = "U";
                titlelbl[6].Text = "DEFAULT";
                titlelbl[7].Text = "CHECK";
                titlelbl[8].Text = "DELETE";
                col = 0;
                FlowLayoutPanel headerpanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                headerpanel.Width = this.myw.right_panel.Width;
                headerpanel.AutoSize = true;
                foreach(Label l in titlelbl)
                {
                    l.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                    l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    headerpanel.Controls.Add(l);
                }
                this.myw.right_panel.Controls.Add(headerpanel);
                this.myw.right_panel.Controls.Add(table);

            }
```

This Function is used to create a dynamic row in the table .Each row contains a button named "DEL"

```
void addrowbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox name = new TextBox(); name.Width = 200;
            ComboBox type = new ComboBox();
            type.Items.AddRange(new string[] {"INTEGER","TEXT","BLOB","NUMERIC","REAL"});
            CheckBox notnull = new CheckBox();
            CheckBox pk = new CheckBox();
            CheckBox ai = new CheckBox();
            CheckBox u = new CheckBox();
            TextBox def = new TextBox(); def.Width = 100;
            TextBox check = new TextBox(); check.Width = 100;
            Button delbtn = new Button(); delbtn.Text = "DEL";delbtn.AutoSize = true;
            delbtn.Click += Delbtn_Click;
            table.Controls.Add(name, 0, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(type, 1, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(notnull, 2, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(pk, 3, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(ai,4, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(u, 5, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(def, 6, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(check,7, tablerow);
            table.Controls.Add(delbtn, 8, tablerow);

            tablerow++;

        }
```

Function for Deleting a Row,
This function will be called whenever a delete button on the table row clicks

```
 private void Delbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            TableLayoutPanelCellPosition tlpcp = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition();
            tlpcp = table.GetPositionFromControl((Control)sender);
            for (int i = 0; i < table.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                var control = table.GetControlFromPosition(i, tlpcp.Row);
                table.Controls.Remove(control);
            }

        }
```

Any code improvement suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Where do you add the `table` to your form?

Comment: please assume that the table added to the form...

Comment: Ok, you should look at the `Control.SuspendLayout` and `Control.ResumeLayout`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thank you it just worked fine.